# Why avoid using caller-sensitive method names in interface classes?

Tags: java, java-security

In [guideline 9-12 / ACCESS-12](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/seccodeguide.html#9-12)

> Avoid using caller-sensitive method names in interface classes

of the [Secure Coding Guidelines for Java SE](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/seccodeguide.html), it is stated that when designing an interface class, one should avoid using methods with the same name and signature of caller-sensitive methods, such as those listed in guidelines [9-8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/seccodeguide.html#9-8), [9-9](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/seccodeguide.html#9-9), and [9-10](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/seccodeguide.html#9-10); and in particular to avoid calling these from default methods on an interface class.

I don't understand why this would be dangerous. E.g. for the following interface:

```
public interface DangerousInterface<T> {

  default T getInstance() {
    T t = newInstance();
    return t;
  }

  T newInstance();
}
```

The `T newInstance()` is defined in `java.lang.Class` and hence, according to the [Secure Coding Guidelines](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/seccodeguide.html), it should not be defined as a method and definitely not called from a default method on an interface class. Why would that be?

Comment: I would imagine that it's because you can inadvertently expose these caller-sensitive methods through a public API.  The dangers of doing that should be obvious.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Please note you're only defining a method in an interface that happens to have the same name and signature as some caller sensitive method. The caller sensitive method itself is not being called.

Comment: Why would you want to define a method in an interface that  happens to have the same name and signature as some caller sensitive method anyway?  Sounds like a recipe for confusion to me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't know, but according to the authors of the security guidelines  it would be a security issue, not another kind of issue.

Comment: There's plenty of speculation to be had.  Mixing names like this increases the probability of an *actual* caller-sensitive method being exposed to the public.  You can't just take Microsoft's word for it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Exposing caller-sensitive methods on itself is not a security problem. The problem is when code with certain "characteristics" (e.g., it has a certain class loader) calls such a caller-sensitive method. When such code is called on behalf of unsafe code, then it could be an issue. However, when defining a method with the same name and signature of a caller-sensitive method on an interface, I don't see how this can be a security problem, especially when the method defined on the interface is not caller sensitive.